# Final velocity of block pulled along a surface using work and energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, free-body-diagram

I have been struggling with this one all day.

A 20kg block is pulled along a level plane with a force of 100N, at an upward angle of 30 degrees above the horizontal.  At d = 15m, the velocity of the block is 8 m/s.  At d = 25m, determine the velocity of the block if the coefficient of friction, uk, is 0.25.

The horizontal pulling force should be 100(cos30) = 86.6N.  The normal force F(N) should be 100(sin30) - (20)(9.81) + F(N) = 0, F(N) = 146.2N.  From there, the friction force F(f) = 146.2 * 0.25  F(f) = 36.55N.

Work equals the change in kinetic energy, so I did the work of the pulling force, minus the friction force, for the distance of 25m - 15 m (i.e. F(pull)d - F(friction)d) equals the change in KE.  86.6(25-15) - (36.55)(25-15) = 0.5(20)(V)^2 - 0.5(20)(8)^2, --> **V = 10.7 m/s**.  The answer is given as 12.6 m/s?

I suspect there's something more I should be doing with the initial state (why else have the block start at d = 15m?). I know the velocity at d = 15m, so I don't need to work out a starting velocity at d = 15m, so how this plays a part I don't know.  I'm getting the right answer on other problems with this approach, but I don't see why it's not working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the net force acting on the block, i.e. the difference between the upward force of $100N$ and the opposing frictional force. So lets find the magnitude of the normal force. The magnitude of the normal force is $\vec N=100\sin(30^\circ)\mathbf{\hat j}-mg\mathbf{\hat j}$, thus the frictional force is given by: $\vec f_k=-\mu_k|\vec N|\mathbf{\hat i}$. So applying Newton's second law we have:
$$\sum\limits_{i}\vec F_i=100\cos(30^\circ)\mathbf{\hat i}-\mu_k(100\sin(30^\circ)-mg)\mathbf{\hat i}=m\vec a.$$

So by the work energy theorem we have:
$$W=\Delta K\implies W={1\over 2}m(v_f^2-v_i^2)={1\over 2}m(v_f^2-64m^2/s^2).$$
From the definition of work:
$$W=|\vec F|d=(100\cos(30^\circ)-\mu_k(100\sin(30^\circ)-mg)(25m-15m).$$
Now, combine these to equations and solve for $v_f$.

Comment: A bit confused, as I think I matched what you wrote.  I calculated the normal force as 146.2N, which matches your procedure.  Then Friction force is 36.55N.  For Work I then get (86.6N - 36.55N)(25-15) = 500.5Nm

Comment: Bah.  Didn't get it all in.   Equating that to KE I get (0.5)(20)(v^2)=1140.5Nm, and V=10.7m/s

Comment: Well, the above is correct, so if you are crunching all the numbers correctly, then the listed answer is an error.

Comment: This is what makes it weird, and this occurred to me last night as I was working the problem backwards.  If the surface is frictionless, then the pulling force can do a *maximum* of (100cos30)(25-15) = 866Nm of work.  However, the change in KE is (0.5)(20)(12.6^2 - 8^2) = 947.6Nm.  So the pulling force *can't* increase the block speed to the provided answer.  Unless there's a concept with W=KE that I am completely missing, I have to agree that the provided answer is incorrect.  That's never happened to me before.

Comment: @Felix Yes, that is good thinking to check the answer like that. But as far as the physics goes, you have got it right, so the listed answer is just wrong. I don't know where you got the problem an answer from, however, sometimes there are mistakes and typos in books, etc. It *does* happen. Makes for a lot of trouble in learning when it does though!

Comment: Can't tell you how much I appreciate the help.  I'm glad that my understanding of the concept was correct.  :)

Comment: @Felix Good luck to you in your work! If my post was helpful, perhaps you might consider upvoting and accepting?

Comment: I am too new to upvote, but I did accept it. :)

Comment: @Felix Thanks I appreciate it!